# Автодобавление текстовых партиций

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Цель: Автоматическое добавление новых партиций при добавлении  нового текстового значения

Ситуация: Поступают записи, в одном поле которых есть повторяющееся текстовое значение. На это поле в целевой для этих данных таблице создана партиция. В качестве значения этого поля может прийти новое значение, которого нет в существующих партициях. Возникает ошибка, связанная с отсутствие соответствующей секции. Списком эти партиции не сделать так, как заранее не известны значения, которые могут поступать.

Вопрос: Можно ли для этого случая организовать автоматическое добавление необходимых секций? Без триггера, только средствами организации таблицы.

Что то типа такого (выдуманный пример):

```
create table char_part
(
    id integer,
    txt varchar2(200)
)
partition by range (txt) interval (1) -- Проблема в автодобавлении нового текст. значения
(
    partition "abc" values less than ('abc'),
    partition "max" values less than (maxvalue) -- Для null - значений
)
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, там есть специальный тип партиции для такого случая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: В версии 11g это невозможно. Лучшее решение - перейти на 12c, так как в этой версии уже введено [автоматическое лист секционирование](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/partition-create-tables-indexes.html#GUID-12150FFB-48E4-4169-9EBE-64974C1CEF2A).

---

Можно решить задачу через [секционирование по interval](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/toc.htm), появившиеся в 11g.
На основе бизнес требований, надо продумать, как вычислить колонку для секционирования. Как например, в этой ветке [спроси у Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5257352600346172725).

Предложение для задачи как в вопросе:

```
create table char_part
(
    id integer,
    txt varchar2(200),
    txt#  generated always as (coalesce (ora_hash (txt, power (2,20)-1), 0)) virtual
)
partition by range (txt#) interval (1) (
    partition "empty" values less than (0),
    partition "undef" values less than (1));

insert into char_part (id, txt) 
    select 1, 'ABC' from dual union all
    select 2, 'DEF' from dual union all
    select 3, 'ZZZ' from dual union all
    select 9, null  from dual;

select table_name, partition_name, high_value 
from user_tab_partitions 
where table_name=upper('char_part'); 

TABLE_NAME PARTITION_NAME       HIGH_VALUE
---------- -------------------- ----------
CHAR_PART  SYS_P1141            222410
CHAR_PART  SYS_P1142            59915
CHAR_PART  SYS_P1143            627928
CHAR_PART  empty                0
CHAR_PART  undef                1
```

Answer (score 1):

В версии 12.2 такое стало возможно.
Для уже существующей таблицы `ALTER TABLE char_part SET PARTITIONING AUTOMATIC;`.
При создании таблицы:

```
... PARTITION BY LIST (txt) AUTOMATIC
(PARTITION part_abc VALUES ('ABC'),
 PARTITION part_def VALUES ('DEF'));
```

Обратите внимание: не `less than`, а `values`, т.е. в таблице секционирование по списку, а не по диапазону значений, иначе с текстовыми данными смысл теряется. В примере также указано, что можно создать секции сразу, несмотря на автоматическое секционирование.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Это как раз то, что нужно.

Comment: Это, видимо, для 12 версии? Так как такой код: 
 create table part_tst
 (
 id integer,
 txt varchar2(200)
 )
 partition by list (txt) automatic
 (
    partition part_abc values ('abc'),
    partition part_def values ('def')
 );
 В 11g вызывает ошибку : ORA-00922: отсутствует или неверна опция И она связана как раз с опцией AUTOMATIC

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст да, это указано в моём ответе :-)

Comment: Да, извините, упустил. У меня 11 (((